# in R, Fitting multilevel mode (linear mixed effect model) by adding variables from two different data set?

Tags: r, multi-level, multilevel-analysis

I fitted a linear mixed effect model using lme4, however, it is a hierarchical structure of data and I have two different data set from level 1 and level 2, but I was struggling to include a variable from both data sets in a linear mixed effect model.

Here is an example:
dt1 is a data set for males and females students in schools a,b and c (they are in order in my data like a,a,a,b,b,b ...). The outcome y is the final test score which is a continuous variable.

```
> dt1
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  School gender     y
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a      m          1
2 b      F          3
3 c      m          5
4 a      F          4
5 b      m          2
6 c      F          1
7 a      m          4
8 b      F          3
9 c      m          1
```

In dt2, q and w are variables at the school level

```
> dt2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  School     q     w
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 a          2   8  
2 b          4   2.5
3 c          4   5
```

I was able to run MLM from dt1 as follow:

```
lmer(y~gender +(1|School), data= dt1)
```

But how can I include a variable from dt2 in the previous model?

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
lmer(y~ gender+dt2$q[dt2$q==q] +(1|School), data = dt1)
```

Any advice, please?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: you probably want to use `merge` (base R) or `full_join` (dplyr) to combine the two data sets, then go from there ...

Comment: `dtcomb = merge(dt1, dt2, by ="School")`